# Cannot connect to database hosted at CentOS VM through SQL Developer on Windows

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, centos, vmware

I've installed Oracle 12c smoothly today and was able to start `lsnrctl` and database.
SQL*Plus connection is okay inside VM.
I've set the IP address to be static @ 192.168.0.20 (CentOS VM).

I am able to ping the VM address from Windows but I cannot connect to the database through SQL Developer inside Windows. This is the error I got:

> The network adapter is unable to establish the connection

I suspect it may be a firewall problem? But I have opened port 1521 using `firewall-cmd`.

Comment: did you add your VM  info to DNS? if not you need to add VM information to windows hosts file under `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and make sure port is opened on Windows

Comment: edit your question with the output of `lsnrctl status`, and `netstat -an | grep 1521`

Comment: Are you sure its port 1521? Are you using Grid Infrastructure? If so you might have created separate listener for Oracle Database.

Answer (score 0):

try to setting listener, for example

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.20)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )   
  )
```

tnsname

```
DBORACLE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.20)(PORT = 2001))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = dboracle)
    )
  )
```